# sending data when clicking a row in GridView that redirects to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

what iam doing is inserting a photo to the database and uploading to the front of my page.
the front page has to show the name and the photo.
iam getting the name from the database and all the photos i have in my UploadedItems folder

here is my front page that has the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="325px" OnRowDataBound="gvSearch_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" ControlStyle-Height="100" ControlStyle-Width="100"  >
    <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

here is my code:

```
    public partial class ListOfItems : System.Web.UI.Page{
    public string ItemImageName, fileName;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            //Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Data=" + "AddItem");
            //Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        }
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedItems/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            DataSet ds = InsertClass.GetItemName(fileName);
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ItemImageName = row["ItemName"].ToString();
                files.Add(new ListItem(ItemImageName, "~/UploadedItems/" + fileName));
                //files.Add(new ListItem(ItemImageName, "~/UploadedItems/" + fileName));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='ItemPage.aspx?id=" +ItemImageName+ e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");

        }
    }
}
```

ok let me explain whats going on in this class first off iam going to the UploadedItems and iam getting every photo in their then iam using their name to query my database with the associated ItemName. now my problem is that when i press the photo it should take me to a page with the  ItemName in my gridView  that i pressed but what its doing is sending the name of the last picture that was added to the GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
   ItemImageName = row["ItemName"].ToString();
   files.Add(new ListItem(ItemImageName,"~/UploadedItems/" + fileName));
   //files.Add(new ListItem(ItemImageName, "~/UploadedItems/" + fileName));
}
```

Your solution to this problem lies here :-

Each time you are looping inside dataset using datarow your ItemImageName gets a newer value, in final loop you are getting last saved imagename from dataset and it's a global variable you are binding same name for different images in gridview rowdatabound event.